# PySpark relationalize doesn't write the data on S3

Tags: xml, amazon-s3, pyspark

I'm pretty new to AWS and PySpark, so excuse me if it is something extremely trivial.

I wonder if someone else experienced this

I'm trying to flatten a bunch of XML files using PySpark renationalize, I have 2 files, 1 about 1Mb, another is about 10Mb.
The smaller 1Mb file is working fine, it writes to the s3 bucket I created, and I can generally work with it.
The larger file is an issue, I can read it, and relationalize runs fine, even returning the data hierarchy (keys), however when I look into the output folder in s3 bucket I can't see any files.

[image]

The folder is empty, the smaller file produces a bunch of partition files in the same folder. It is really puzzling as I would think that if it returns the keys then it read the flat partitioned data from somewhere, however the folder is empty as I mentioned. What am I missing? Is it something to do with the s3 limitations / settings, or the size of the file?

Just a snipped of the code in question, shouldn't be a code issue however as it works on one of the files fine.

#Create a DynamicFrame from a table in the AWS Glue Data Catalog

```
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database='landingsite', table_name='crawler_item_xml')
dyf.printSchema()
#flaten and write the partitioned data to s3
dfc = dyf.relationalize("root", "s3://mikas-rubbishbin/output/")
dfc.keys()
```